# Quantifier 'for some but not all'

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let's consider the quantifier corresponding to the expression 'for some but not all'. Is it possible to define the universal quantifier in terms of this quantifier and sentence connectives only?

Comment: I propose using a tophat in honor of Abraham Lincoln.

Comment: The negation of your quantifier is, 'either for all or for none' and I doubt that it's possible to define $\forall$ in terms of this.

Comment: @Alraxite that's exactly why this quantifier should not be defined in a way that renders It's negation as 'either for all or for none', I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define $\forall$ and $\exists$ in term of the expression :

> 'for some but not all'.

**1)** May we assume that the translation of the expression is :

> $\exists x \phi(x) \land \lnot \forall x \phi(x)$ ?

This sentence implies (if I'm right) that :

> - the *universe* is not empty
> - something in the universe is $\phi$
> - something is not $\phi$
> - there are at least two thing in the *universe*.

But the sentence is also equivalent to :

> $\exists x \phi(x) \land \exists x \lnot \phi(x)$

**2)** *If* my "translation" is right and *if* my inferences are also right, I doubt that we can define $\exists$.

The $\exists$ quantifier implies the existence of *at least* **one** object in the *universe*, whlie the new "quantifier" implies the existence of *at least* **two** objects.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly as stated this is not possible without resorting to a trick of some kind.

I'll use $Y x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ as the quantifier *for some but not all*, following its representation in the [logical hexagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_hexagon).

If your domain has only a single element in it, then the value of $Y x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ is always false. However $\varphi$ might hold or might fail for the sole element of the domain.

Here's a partial solution.

---

Suppose the domain has cardinality at least $1$ and that we have a constant symbol $c$.

$$ \exists x \mathop. \varphi(x) \;\;\text{iff}\;\; \varphi(c) \lor (Y x \mathop. \varphi(x)) $$

As proof, suppose $\varphi$ holds for $c$, then $\varphi(c)$ holds and $\exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ holds.

Suppose $\varphi$ does not hold for $c$, but for holds for some $d \neq c$. In this case, $\exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ holds and $Y x . \varphi(x)$ holds.

Suppose $\varphi$ does not hold for any element in the domain. Then $\exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ fails and $\varphi(c)$ fails and $Y x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ also fails.

Answer (score -2):

Let's call $\triangle$ the quantifier. Then $\exists x : P(x)$ should be equivalent to $(\triangle x : P(x)) \vee (\triangle x : \lnot P(x))$

Comment: One direction is false: $\Delta x ( P(x) )\vee \Delta x (\neg P(x))$ is false when $P(x)$ holds of every x but $\exists x (P(x))$ is true.

Comment: Oops yes you are right!